# I need to do a subtraction in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

i need to do a subtraction in haskell, and the result add an list, but the new list doesn't give me the real valors

for example: [1,2,3,4,5]

- prom = (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 5 = 3
- subs = (1 - 3) = -2 add to list
- subs = (2 - 3) = -1 add to list
- subs = (3 - 3) = 0 add to list
- subs = (4 - 3) = 1 add to list
- subs = (5 - 3) = 2 add to list
- new list = [-2,-1,0,1,2]

this's the code:

```
add (x:xs) = x + add xs

prom (x:xs) = add (x:xs) `div` length (x:xs)

subs [] = []
subs (x:xs) = x - prom (x:xs) : subs xs
```

how i can do that? and why the results is different?

Comment: for example: [1,2,3,4,5] prom = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 / 5 = 3

subs = (1 - 3) = -2 add to list subs = (2 - 3) = -1 add to list subs = (3 - 3) = 0 add to list subs = (4 - 3) = 1 add to list subs = (5 - 3) = 2 add to list

new list = [-2,-1,0,1,2]

Comment: for the moment, yes, but i thought to use "/"

Comment: `add` is already defined for you, as the `sum` function.

Answer (score 4):

`prom (x:xs)` will return the average for that list, but if you recurse, you thus consider the *tail* of the list, and you thus calculate the average on the remaining elements.

This means that your list will contain `[1-3, 2-3, 3-4, 4-4, 5-5]`, so `[-2, -1, -1, 0, 0]`. You should thus determine the average of the entire list, and subtract that from all elements, so:

```
subs :: [Int] -> [Int]
subs xs = map (subtract (prom xs)) xs
```

Your `add` should also consider the empty list case:

```
add :: [Int] -> Int
add [] = 0
add (x:xs) = x + add xs
```

and for `prom` you can work with an `xs` variable as pattern to bind with the entire list:

```
prom :: [Int] -> Int
prom xs = add xs `div` length xs
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I apologise in advance for being unable to say that using `(x:xs)` or `list@(x:xs)` in `prom` leaves you with a compiler warning of an incomplete pattern that might prompt @YahelDaOng some day to write a safer version once they understand the Maybe data type whereas this one just gives you runtime errors instead. Personally I'm not a fan of swapping compiler warnings for runtime errors. I agree that @YahelDaOng more urgently needs to know what you taught them - that you can process the entire list by calling it `xs`, you don't have to call it `(x:xs)` unless you need x.